# Using libcurl to access proxy

Tags: c, curl, proxy, libcurl

I want to access a proxy using libcurl in my C code. I read that with this command I can configure libcurl to access the proxy:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:96666");
```

But is that all I have to do? Do I need to open a socket?

Any tip will be very helpful,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's all you need - assuming it is a HTTP proxy and you fix the port number, because 96666 is not a valid port! :-)

See the [CURLOPT_PROXY](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PROXY.html) man page for more details.